# Will FIDE extend time limits on certain qualifications given the suspension of chess during Covid-19?

Tags: fide

We already know that there has been [very little FIDE rated chess played in April](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-much-fide-rated-chess-was-played-in-april-2020). There are a number of areas where FIDE has time limits. For example:

1. Unrated players have [26 months to get results](https://old.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=197&view=article) which qualify them for a FIDE rating
2. Players are [classed as "inactive"](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B02RBRegulations) if they don't play any FIDE rated chess for 1 year
3. Arbiters are [classed as "inactive"](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/RegsClassChessArbiters.pdf) if they don't arbit any FIDE rated competitions for 2 years.

Will FIDE look at extending these time limits in view of the current Covid-19 suspension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a [partial answer](https://fide.com/news/796) from FIDE:

> WHEREAS, since the onset of the Covid-19 pandemic, it has been possible for only a reduced number of FIDE rated tournaments to take place. As a result, it is likely that many players who would under normal conditions be playing rated games will find that they are unable to do so and will therefore be marked as inactive.

> The FIDE Council has considered this problem and has decided on the advice of the Qualification Commission (QC) that, from the November 2020 list UNTIL FURTHER NOTICE, **the period specified in the definition of inactivity will be increased from 12 months to 24 months.**