# As we come out of lockdown, how much FIDE rated chess was played in June 2020?

Tags: rating, fide, statistics

I asked a [similar question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-much-fide-rated-chess-was-played-in-april-2020) about chess during lockdown. Now that some countries are coming out of lockdown and chess is resuming FIDE has published [data for June](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml).

NB I looked at May data and as far as I could tell FIDE just repeated the April tournament data with updates from federations for corrections to previous data and new registrations but no new tournament data. The June data does contain new tournament data.

What does the June data tell us about chess coming out of lockdown?

Specifically:

1. How many games (or half-games) of FIDE rated chess (standard, rapid and blitz) were played in June, by country?
2. How many players from which countries played FIDE rated chess (standard, rapid and blitz) in June?
3. How does this compare with the same data for June 2019 for total game counts and total player counts? (Break down by country would be too much)

These statistics should give us some idea what progress is being made and how much further we have to go to get back close to normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the latest [July 2020 rating list](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml) and loaded the data into my database and ran a few queries.

First one to show the number of players who played standard, rapid or blitz per federation sorted by standard players descending. I also included the number of active players in the federation to give an idea of which federations were more active. I excluded federations where the number of players playing was less than 4 on the grounds that they were likely living and playing in other federations. That still gave an impressive list of 33 federations which look as if they are back playing chess.

Code    ActivePlayers   Standard    Rapid   Blitz
CZE 10838   2543    17  16
SVK 6704    1357    54  0
SWE 5331    449 1   0
CRO 7654    351 14  54
GRE 20595   338 0   0
DEN 5496    134 0   0
SRB 7436    112 75  69
ISR 4104    96  0   1
NOR 5165    93  0   0
POL 21407   85  38  40
HUN 7928    80  6   1
LAT 2758    69  86  99
MNE 822 69  0   0
SUI 3170    66  6   1
BUL 3038    60  1   0
ISL 1842    36  54  60
FIN 1308    36  0   0
LTU 3813    32  59  22
SLO 4320    31  44  82
NCA 712 23  0   39
GER 22613   22  1   2
EST 1517    22  0   6
BEL 5602    14  0   1
RUS 68077   8   3   1
ITA 18332   6   10  1
AUT 5640    4   2   0
UKR 11853   4   2   22
FRA 55783   4   1   2
TUR 36523   4   0   0
ESP 45444   4   0   1
IRQ 1515    2   47  0
THA 1082    0   14  0
KGZ 2688    0   10  0

What stands out as quite remarkable in that list is that over 20% of Czech and Slovak active players played last month!

Next a query to show the sum of standard players, rapid players and blitz players.

That gave for June 2020:

Standard = 6171
Rapid = 551
Blitz = 524

By comparison for June 2019:

Standard = 35708
Rapid = 18712
Blitz = 10569

Two things stand out

1. More than 60% of standard chess played in June 2020 was played in the Czech and Slovak republics
2. Standard accounted for far more of the chess played in June 2020 than in June 2019.

Next a query to show the sum of standard+rapid+blitz games per federation. Here is the top 20. Click on the federation link to see the list of tournaments reported for that federation in June 2020:

Code    Total   Standard    Rapid   Blitz
[CZE](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=CZE&rating_period=2020-07-01)    16002   7899    100 204
[SVK](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=SVK&rating_period=2020-07-01)    4848    2424    132 0
[LAT](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=LAT&rating_period=2020-07-01)    2625    599 672 1427
[SRB](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=SRB&rating_period=2020-07-01)    2097    435 560 1227
[CRO](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=CRO&rating_period=2020-07-01)    2074    719 80  636
[GRE](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=GRE&rating_period=2020-07-01)    1834    917 0   0
[SLO](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=SLO&rating_period=2020-07-01)    1663    138 300 1387
[POL](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=POL&rating_period=2020-07-01)    1221    441 401 339
[HUN](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=HUN&rating_period=2020-07-01)   1213    601 8   11
[SWE](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=SWE&rating_period=2020-07-01)   1108    554 7   0
[ISL](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=ISL&rating_period=2020-07-01)   869 93  330 683
[NOR](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=NOR&rating_period=2020-07-01)   776 388 0   0
[DEN](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=DEN&rating_period=2020-07-01)   754 377 0   0
[LTU](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=LTU&rating_period=2020-07-01)   714 230 404 254
[BUL](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=BUL&rating_period=2020-07-01)   708 354 9   0
[MNE](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=MNE&rating_period=2020-07-01)   606 303 0   0
[NCA](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=NCA&rating_period=2020-07-01)   575 167 0   241
[SUI](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=SUI&rating_period=2020-07-01)   503 246 36  11
[EST](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=EST&rating_period=2020-07-01)   354 144 0   66
[ISR](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=ISR&rating_period=2020-07-01)   319 155 0   9

The sum of games for June 2020:

Standard = 17562
Rapid = 3774
Blitz = 6844

For comparison the same figures for June 2019:

Standard = 247057
Rapid = 148693
Blitz = 121143

Digging deeper into the data for the Czech republic, you can see the tournaments reported for
June 2020 for the Czech Republic [here](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=CZE&rating_period=2020-07-01) and for
June 2019 for the Czech Republic [here](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=CZE&rating_period=2019-07-01)

43 Czech tournaments reported in June 2020 against 21 in June 2019. It looks very much like in June they aimed to catch up with all the matches and tournaments they missed during the lockdown.